# Refresh Jquery Pageslide plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side-panel using [Jquery Pageslide](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-pageslide) that allows the user to select dates and companies for the application. The plugin copies the div in the reference element into another Node (`#pageslide`) like so on initialization.

```
<body>
....
<!-- REFERENCED ELEMENT -->
<div id="l-picker>
  <div id="l-picker-date">...</div>
  <div id="l-picker-company">...</div>
</div>
<!-- PAGE SLIDE PANEL -->
<div id="#pageslide">
  <div id="l-picker>
    <div id="l-picker-date">...</div>
    <div id="l-picker-company">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

However, changes to the referenced element do not update the #pageslide element. How can I refresh the page slide panel and keep all the attached events?

Comment: Take a look at the following questions answers: [Jquery Pageslide not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042486/jquery-pageslide-not-working).

Comment: Thanks @BrettMcCarty - I'm not having a problem with it working. I'm having a problem refreshing it. I don't want to have to slide it out and then back in to make it refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @imrane, misunderstood the problem. It does not look like there is a refresh method on the pageSlide plugin. Would it work to update the #pageslide div when the referenced element is updated?

Something like:

```
$('#pageslide').html('<div id='l-picker'>...</div>');
```

Comment: id have to reattach all the events as well then - its a pain - but I guess without a refresh method it will have to do. Thanks.